# Десериализовать объект JsonResult в список

Tags: c#, json

Есть переменная, содержащая объект типа JsonResult

```
var jsonData = GetJsonData(string someValue);
```

jsonData содержит коллекцию объектов типа Test

есть класс соответственно, с помощью которого хотел десериализовать в список

```
class Test { public string first {get; set;}  public string second{get; set;}}
```

Пробую так

```
var result= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(jsonData);
```

Но так не выходит.

функция GetJsonData возвращает объект

```
return new JsonResult() { Data = new { someObjects // список объектов типа Test } };
```

ошибка следующая

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'string'

Что не так сделано?

Comment: Добавьте реализацию функции `GetJsonData`, а так же пример строки которую пытаетесь десериализовать, т.е. содержимое `jsonData`. Кроме того, если вы получаете ошибку, стоит привести сообщение об ошибке и StackTrace, а так же пояснить выражение _так не выходит._

Comment: Добавьте ее реализацию в вопрос.

Comment: Мне кажется сообщение об ошибке предельно ясно: В метод который принимает строку вы передаете объект. Передавайте строку и все будет хорошо

Comment: в том то и дело, что у меня не строка.) Тогда бы  вопроса не было

Comment: Метод DeserializeObject преобразует строку в объект. Правильно ли я вас понял, что вы хотите вытащить объект из JsonResult и преобразовать его в List<Test>?

Comment: Да, всё правильно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пересмотрите свою архитектуру. В нормальной архитектуре у вас не должно возникать желания упаковать объект в JsonResult чтобы потом распаковывать его обратно.

Конкретно же по задаче, можно сделать так:

```
var result = JObject.FromObject(jsonData.Data).Property("someObjects").Value.ToObject<List<Test>>();
```

Comment: судя по всему должно было быть что-то вроде `JToken.FromObject(jsonData.Data.someobjects)` - потому что судя по вопросу - список именно в поле объекта. Но так не получится потому что `Data` - Это `object`

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, спасибо Вам за помощь. Как вы предложили заработало.